# Calculate double integral with signum-function.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let
>
> $$f(x, y) :=
> \begin{cases}
> sgn(xy) \over x^2 + y^2,  & \text{$(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus ${0}$$} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> be a function with
>
> $${\rm sgn}(xy) := 
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{$xy > 0$} \\
> -1, & \text{$xy < 0$} \\
> 0, & \text{$xy = 0$} 
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Calculate
>
> $$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y) d\lambda(x) d\lambda(y)$$ and
>
> $$\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y) d\lambda(y) d\lambda(x).$$

**Edit:**

I deleted my former approach and would like to try a new one:

We are allowed to assume that

$$f = f_+ + f_-.$$

Hence, we are allowed to write the inner integral as

$$\int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y)_+ d\lambda(x) + \int_{\Bbb R} f(x, y)_- d\lambda(x) = \int_{\Bbb R} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} d\lambda(x) + \int_{\Bbb R}  {-1 \over x^2 + y^2} d\lambda(x).$$

Using the linearity of the integral, we receive:

$$\int_{\Bbb R} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} d\lambda(x) - \int_{\Bbb R} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} d\lambda(x).$$

Both integrals are identical, hence their difference is $0$, and so is the outer integral then.

Is that a valid answer?

Comment: What does that symbol $\;d\lambda(x)\;$ mean??

Comment: You integrate with respect to $\lambda(x)$.

Comment: @B Thanks, I already knew that: **what is** $\;\lambda\;$ , though??

Comment: It's the Lebesgue Measure.

Comment: I think that the point of the exercise is that the *iterated* integrals are both zero while the function isn't integrable. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem.

Comment: Maybe. But where are my calculations wrong then?

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why I get downvoted?

Comment: The hint appears useless or worse.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{sgn} a\,\mathrm d\phi=0$. So with your transformations you actually get $0\cdot\infty$ which is an indeterminate form. Note that if you integrate over any finite ball, you'll get $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Do you possibly have another approach then the two that were already given in the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's [measurable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is not [Lebesgue integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)
   $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\! d\lambda(x,y)~|f(x,y)|~\stackrel{r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{=}~2\pi \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \! \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r}~\stackrel{\text{hint}}{=}~\infty. $$
   cf. Tonelli's theorem. Therefore we cannot use [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). In particular, OP's successive integrations in polar coordinates (of the function $f$, as opposed to the function $|f|$) are unjustified, i.e. not relevant for OP's mentioned exercise.
2. In rectangular coordinates for fixed $y$, we calculate:
   $$\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}:~~  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! d\lambda(x)~|f(x,y)|~=~\frac{\pi}{|y|}~<~\infty,$$
   so the function $x\mapsto  f(x,y)=-f(-x,y)$ is a Lebesgue integrable [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions). Hence its integral vanishes
   $$\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}:~~  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! d\lambda(x)~ f(x,y) ~=~0.$$
3. Therefore the function
   $$ y~~\mapsto~~ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! d\lambda(x)~ f(x,y) ~=~0 ~~\text{ a.e.} $$
   vanishes [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), so that the sought-for double integral becomes
   $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\! d\lambda(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! d\lambda(x)~ f(x,y) ~=~0. $$
4. There is a similar conclusion for the function $y\mapsto  f(x,y)$ for fixed $x$ because of the symmetry $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Comment: For showing that the function is not Lebesgue-integrable, I would still prefer switching to polar coordinates. It is way easier than thinking about a clever substitution. By switching to polar coordinates and applying Tonelli, you receive the integral $\int_{\Bbb R} \int_{\Bbb R} {1 \over r^2} r dr d\phi$, thus, you can apply the hint directly.

Comment: Besides that, I have never encountered the term "odd function" or how it is related to an Lebesgue-integral.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I understand what odd functions are, but I believe that there is a simpler way to do this since it is an old exam question. Since we never talked about integrating odd functions, I don't think that this is what our professor wants us to achieve. Do you know any other solution? And wouldn't it still work with polar coordinates somehow?

Comment: Or applying $f = f_+ + f_-$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

See, that for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $f(x,y)=-f(-x,y)$

**Hint 2**
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) dx =\int_\mathbb{R_-} f(x,y) dx +\int_\mathbb{R_+} f(x,y) dx = \\
=\int_\mathbb{R_+} f(-x,y) dx +\int_\mathbb{R_+} f(x,y) dx$$

**Hint 3**
$$\text{sgn}(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)) = \text{sgn}(\sin(2\varphi)) = \begin{cases}1&, \varphi \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi)&, k\in \mathbb{Z}\\
-1&, \varphi \in (\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, (k+1)\pi)&, k\in \mathbb{Z}\\
0&, x= \frac{k\pi}{2} &, k\in \mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$

**Hint 4**
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \text{sgn}(\cos \varphi \sin \varphi)}{r} d\varphi = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{ \text{sgn}(\cos \varphi \sin \varphi)}{r} d\varphi = 0$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you are refering to? Are my calculations wrong in general?

Comment: I don't see what you are up to with your hints. Can't you just tell me where my calculations went wrong first?